# JSON generation using TransformMessage in Mule

Tags: json, mule-studio, dataweave

I am trying to generate the following JSON ...

```
{ "myVariable": [ { "LoopId": "2" }, { "LoopId": "3" }, { "LoopId": "4" } ] }
```

and able to achieve this with the class code ... with Java node (in Mule)

```
package com.mule.integrations.pakage;

public class CreateJsonPayload {
public String generateJsonPayload(String last) {

 int lastInt = Integer.parseInt(last);      
 String jsonPayload = "{ \"MyVariable\" : [ ";

 for (int i=1; i <= lastInt; i++) {         
     jsonPayload = jsonPayload + "{ \"LoopId\":\"" + i + "\" }";
     if (i < lastInt) jsonPayload = jsonPayload + ",";
 }

 jsonPayload = jsonPayload + " ]}";     
 return jsonPayload;
}


}
```

As I have to generate this JSON based on the variable, with the number of "LoopId" nodes in JSON.

for example, varNumberOfLoops = 5, I need to generate {"LoopId":"1"} through 5.

if I wanted to generate the same through "TransformMessage" node with DataWeave, how could I do that?

any pointers towards this is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that a part of your code is not correctly formatted. It would be better if you format it by adding the 4 spaces in front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be work for you..

```
 %dw 1.0
 %output application/json
 %var resultStart = '1' as :number
 %var resultEnd = flowVars.varNumberOfLoops as :number
 %var range = [[resultStart][0] .. [resultEnd][0]]
 ---
 {
     "myVariable": range map {
         "LoopId"    : $ as :string
     }
 }
```

Comment: This code form also working to produce the desired result -

 %dw 1.0
 %output application/json
 %function iterate(response,counter) response when counter-1 >= flowVars.varNumberOfLoops  otherwise iterate(response ++ [{"LoopId":counter}],counter+1)
  ---
 {
     myVariable:iterate([],1)
 }

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give you the solution .Hope this helps.

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <set-variable variableName="myVar" value="#[message.payload.myVariable]" doc:name="myVar"/>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
 %output application/json
 %var a=flowVars.myVar
 ---
  "myVariable":
 [1 .. a] map {
     "LoopId"    : $
 }]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="JSONNNNN #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

and the output is ::

```
{
"myVariable": [
    {
        "LoopId": 1
    },
    {
        "LoopId": 2
    },
    {
        "LoopId": 3
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Thank You for the very quick response.

resulting an error in Any point Studio - 

Invalid input "a]", expected is, *, <=, replace, <, >=, as, or, >>, ~=, binaryOp, match, -, ==, default, :range, +, !=, when, and, / or >

Comment: We defined a dataweave var and assigned my variable with flowVars.myvar. I tested this in my Anypoint studio and working as expected .If APS itself is not starting means you need to look at compile time errors APS is throwing .Pls post complete flow

Comment: <flow name="test2Flow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/testing" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-variable variableName="myVariable" value="5" doc:name="myVariable"/>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var a=flowVars.myVariable
 ---
  "myVariable":
 [1 .. a] map {
     "LoopId"    : $
 }]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="#[payload]"  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        
    </flow>

Comment: I was also trying to do the same in DataWeave earlier and resulted with this error 

expected is, *, <=, replace, <, >=, as, or, >>, ~=, binaryOp, match, -, ==, default, :range, +, !=, when, and, / or > –

even before I run the flow... this is either formatting or compiling error

Comment: I removed space between variable 'a' and '.' (dot), the it compiled... 

but resulted this error @ runtime

Exception while executing: 
 [1 ..a] map {
  ^
Type mismatch for 'Descendants Selector ..' operator
     found :number
  required :array.

Comment: The edited one also does not really help... just a note - 

the input variable is not an array or JSON, its a simple string or int variable, based on that number (1 to n), either Array or JSON has to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as per your requirement.

From POSTMan send this request

```
{ "myVariable":3 }
```

And then below is the flow

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8088" basePath="/config" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

<flow name="TestFlow" >
   <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/testXml" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <set-variable variableName="myVar" value="#[message.payload.myVariable]" doc:name="myVar"/>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
 %output application/json
 %var a=flowVars.myVar
 ---
  "myVariable":
 [1 .. a] map {
     "LoopId"    : $
 }]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="JSONNNNN #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>   


</flow>
```

and below is the response.

```
{
"myVariable": [
    {
        "LoopId": 1
    },
    {
        "LoopId": 2
    },
    {
        "LoopId": 3
    }
]
```

}